# Svelte scrollY changes value when sticky element resizes

Tags: css, scroll, svelte, transition, sticky

I want to change the appearance (make it take up less height) of a sticky navbar when I start scrolling. But when I do this the height change results in the scrollY value changing resulting in a loop of it flickering/switching between the large and small navbar, until the difference is big enough. That is when it switches to the smaller navbar.

I also don't know how to transition between the two without having a short period of time where the one fades out and the other fades in, resulting in what i believe are both navbars being visible at the same time.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { fade } from 'svelte/transition';

    let scrollY : number = 0;
</script>

<style>
    nav {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .menubar {
        display: grid;
        column-gap: 2.25em;

        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);

        padding: 1.5em;
    }

    .menubar-small {
        display: grid;
        column-gap: 2.25em;

        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);

        padding: 0.5em;
    }
</style>

<svelte:window bind:scrollY={scrollY}/>

<nav>
    {#if scrollY <= 40}
    <div transition:fade class="menubar">
        <div class="menubarElem left">
            <ThemeSwitcher></ThemeSwitcher> 
        </div>
        <div class="menubarElem center align-self-end">
            <slot name="pagelinks"/>
        </div>
        <div class="menubarElem right">
            <DateTime></DateTime>
        </div>
    </div>
    {:else}
    <div transition:fade class="menubar-small">
        <div class="menubarElem left">
            <ThemeSwitcher></ThemeSwitcher> 
        </div>
        <div class="menubarElem center align-self-end">
            <slot name="pagelinks"/>
        </div>
        <div class="menubarElem right">
            <DateTime></DateTime>
        </div>
    </div>
    {/if}
</nav>
```

I have tried changing it to `{#if scrollY == 0}`, which has a similar effect for me, because it doesn't always register the top of the page as 0 (I suspect it has something to do with smooth scrolling).

I already have changed a lot about the layout, so maybe I am approaching the problem from the wrong angle and am overlooking something.

Comment: If you only change the padding, I would rather use a regular CSS transition instead.